# English verbs with more than one past tense

Tags: english, verbs, tense

In English, there are verbs that have two valid past participles. An example for such a verb would be *sow* which has the two forms *sowed* and *sown*.

Are there English verbs that have more than one valid past tenses?

Comment: Are you asking about past participles or past tenses? 'Sowed' is usually described as the simple past tense while 'sown' is the past participle.

Comment: I was asking about past tenses. According to dictionary.com, *sowed* can also be used as the past participle: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sow

Comment: If you're only asking about past tense forms, why did you cite the participle "sown" in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kneeled / knelt, chided / chid. Irregular verbs that became regularized.

Comment: Also you have regular verbs that have become irregular: dived / dove.

Comment: @guifa Well, in some dialects, perhaps. Elsewhere, "dive" is still regular. Likewise, "telt" is the p.t. of "tell" in some dialects.

Some more irregular verbs where regular forms are also used: strive (strove/strived, striven/strived); thrive, similarly; learn (learnt/learned); spell (spelt/spelled)

Comment: Learned and learnt is an interesting case. There is a red squiggly line under the latter as I type BTW.

Answer (score 2):

While the trend seems to be towards the regularization of verbs, some have gone the other way:

The preterite of **dig** was ***[digged](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=7QqzTicz7MAC&dq=%22digged%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)*** until the 1600s, when it began to change to ***dug***. Some [irregular verbs references](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=nrZzAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&dq=%22digged%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22digged%22&f=false) still retain both forms.

More recently, in some American dialects, we now have ***snuck*** (for sneaked) and ***dove*** (for dived). Personally, they make me shudder.